# Excel Question: How can I have have a column where I can change the data on that on which on another sheet reflects the data that has been changed

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Starting off with this sample

[image: First Photo]

As Cell A1 is a list box/drop down with values off data from CELL F2:F6

[[image: Second Photo][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx6o8.png)

As Cell A2:A6 is also a list box/drop down with values. Sample would be Pass and Fail.

[image: Third Photo]

As I change the values on CELLS A2:A6 based on selected value in the list box/drop down, G2:K2 reflects all the updated changes.

[image: Fourth Photo]

[image: Fifth Photo]

If cell A1's value is changed to update other rows, the same goes with the other row.

[image: Sixth Photo]

Comment: I've been trying to make my excel more organized and easier for editing and tracking since there are too many rows and columns for the array for manual editing and updating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA to paste your input in another cell.

First, define names on ranges as follows

- TargetRow: CELL A1
- TargetData: CELL A2:A6
- Rows: CELL F2:F6

[image: screenshot of defining names on ranges]

Then, put the following VBA in under [your sheet]
[image: VBA editor]

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal rng As Range)
    If Not Intersect(rng, Range("TargetData")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim rowStr As String: rowStr = Range("TargetRow").Value2
        Dim l As Long: l = Range("Rows").Count
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To l
            If Range("Rows").Cells(i, 1).Value2 = rowStr Then
                Dim n As Long: n = Range("TargetData").Count
                Dim j As Long
                For j = 1 To n
                    Range("Rows").Cells(1, 1).Offset(i - 1, j).Value2 = Range("TargetData").Cells(1, 1).Offset(j - 1, 0).Value2
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Worksheet_Change() is triggered if you make some changes on your sheet. Then check the change is done in TargetData range. Using "for" loop, find which row is to be updated.

Comment: I shall check this out. I apologize for the late reply. It was the weekend and Im back to work now. :)